# IBM Mobilefirst: Subscribe to SMS Notification in Native Android/IOS code

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am checking for SMS notification subscription code in Native Android and IOS. I was able to find code for hybrid app but can some body help with a sample code for native Android and IOS.

I was checking the below link 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/sms-notifications/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for SMS in native applications in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1. You can do this, though, in IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. See:

- Notifications overview: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/
- Handling SMS notifications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-sms-notifications/